# How to create 2 loops?

Tags: file, loops, powershell, foreach

I have a csv file with NetworkID and NewFileName field. and I have bunch of files on a fileshare. The file name under the file share named after domain_networkid_Lthumb.jpg.

The idea is read each line from csv then find the file using contains (i guess). If a file is found that at least contains networkid_lthumb then rename this file to NewFileName.jpg.

What is the best way to do this? I have following code. and I just want to make it's efficient.

```
# Renames file based on CSV
$csvFile = Import-csv 'c:\userdata.csv'
$files = Get-ChildItem "c:\eePics\"
foreach($user in $csvFile)
{
    $account = $user.networkid
    $keyword = $account + "_LThumb" 
    $file = Get-Content $files.FullName
    $ContainsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $keyword}   
    if($ContainsWord -contains $true)
    {       
        Rename-Item $_.name -NewName $user.NewFileName
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understand you correctly you want to get all files whoms name matches the networkid and username + "_LThumb" and rename them? Then your code does not do what you expect it to do

Comment: if username+_lthumb matches or contains NetworkID then rename the file the new file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you are trying to achieve this should work:

```
$csvFile = Import-csv "C:\userdata.csv"
$filePath = "C:\eepics\"
$destination = "C:\example\folder\"

foreach($user in $csvFile){
$filename = $user.networkid + "_LThumb"
Get-Childitem $filePath | where {$_.Name -match $filename} | Rename-Item -NewName $user.NewFileName
Copy-Item $filePath$($user.NewFileName) -Destination $destination
}
```

Note that the NewFileName in your csv has to contain the File-Extension (e.g. ".jpg")

`-contains` is used to test if a set (for example an array) contains a value. 
boolean comparisons like you are trying to do in your if statement should be done like this:

```
if($variable){}
```

If `$variable` is True the block will be executed

Regarding your code:

```
$file = Get-Content $files.FullName
```

will actually get the content (and if i say content i mean it) of all files in the directory C:\eepics\

```
$ContainsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $keyword}
```

will cycle through all contents of all files you got line by line and see if something matches $keyword

**Update:** added code to copy the file after renaming because of user request

Comment: Should we use contains instead of match because files in the file share contain prefix of domain name and it varies.

Comment: Hi Green, let us clarify this in Chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63429/discussion-between-green-code-and-paul

Comment: I am sorry but i´m still not sure if you want to find files with a NAME like "username_lthumb" or if you want to search the contents of the files for this string. please clarify and if possible provide sample values

Comment: so the actual file name looks like this domainA_username_LThumb.jpg or domainC_username2_LThumb.jpg etc. The csv file has the actual network id or user name without the domain. So idea is if networkid has a match in the filename from fileshare then rename.

Comment: cool. let me give it a try in the morning. and I will let you know. thanks Paul

Comment: Paul: I am not seeing reference to fileshare files $files = Get-ChildItem "c:\eePics\" in your code.

Comment: @GreenCode yup you´re right, forgot that one. will update the answer

Comment: Thanks Paul. Worked like charm. Is there a way change the modified date so I can sort the renamed files and copy it to it's final home. Thanks. Nat Green

Comment: do you have to move it manually? please join the chatroom in my first comment if possible so we can keep the comment section somewhat short

Comment: chat room wants me to have 20 points before i can do chat. I am new to this site. I dont have to move them manually. I can create a subfolder or script can create a folder anywhere and copy this new files there.